# Getting Controller details in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET 4.x, there is a `ReflectedControllerDescriptor`class which resides in `System.Web.Mvc`. This class provides the descriptor of a controller.

In my previous applications, I used to do this:

```
var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType);

var actions = (from a in controllerDescriptor.GetCanonicalActions()
              let authorize = (AuthorizeAttribute)a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault()
              select new ControllerNavigationItem
                 {
                    Action = a.ActionName,
                    Controller = a.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
                    Text =a.ActionName.SeperateWords(),
                    Area = GetArea(typeNamespace),
                    Roles = authorize?.Roles.Split(',')
                 }).ToList();

return actions;
```

The problem is I can't find any equivalent of this class in ASP.NET Core. I came across `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`which seems to provide limited details.

**The Question**

My goal is to write an equivalent code in ASP.NET Core. How do I achieve that?

Your help is really appreciated

Comment: Perhaps try injecting `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` and using that to retrieve the desired instances of `ControllerActionDescriptor` as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4023)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I came across IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider which seems to
>   provide limited details.

Probably you don't cast `ActionDescriptor` to `ControllerActionDescriptor`. Related info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269993/5426333)

> My goal is to write an equivalent code in ASP.NET Core. How do I
>   achieve that?

Here is my attempt in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();
    var ctrlActions = provider.ActionDescriptors.Items
            .Where(x => (x as ControllerActionDescriptor)
            .ControllerTypeInfo.AsType() == typeof(Home222Controller))
            .ToList();
    foreach (var action in ctrlActions)
    {
         var descriptor = action as ControllerActionDescriptor;
         var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerName;
         var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
         var areaName = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo
                .GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>().RouteValue;
    }
```